# Regression in R after removing outliers

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, lm

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
time        values    outlier  
20/01/2010   11         no          
20/02/2010   12         no
20/03/2010   11         no
20/04/2010   12         no
20/05/2010   10         no
20/06/2010   20         yes
20/07/2010   11         no
20/02/2010   12         no
```

I would like to run a regression on this dataframe with `values` as my independent variable and `time` as dependent variable. But I would like to exclude all the rows with "yes" in the `outlier` column.

Here is what I tried:

```
temp <- subset(df, outlier==yes)
fit  <- lm(as.vector(temp$value) ~ as.vector(temp$time))
slope   <- fit$coefficients[[2]]
intrcpt <- fit$coefficients[[1]]

temp$regression_points <- temp$value*fit$coefficients[[2]]+fit$coefficients[[1]]
```

Now I would like to use the obtained regression model to predict the original values from `temp` and put the results back into the original dataframe like this:

```
time        values    outlier      regression_points  
20/01/2010   11         no                11
20/02/2010   12         no                11
20/03/2010   11         no                11
20/04/2010   12         no                11
20/05/2010   10         no                11
20/06/2010   20         yes               
20/07/2010   11         no                11
20/02/2010   12         no                11
```

How can I tackle this problem.

Comment: You could start by producing a minimal reproducible example. Inlcuding a sample of your data frame with `dput`. Besidess, are you aware of outlier robust regression methods? They should make it unnecessary to remove the outliers beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new data frame, `df2`, that has outliers NA'd out and then fit that with `na.exclude`:

```
df2 <- transform(df, values = ifelse(outlier == "no", values, NA))
fm <- lm(values ~ time, df2, na.action = na.exclude)
transform(df, fitted = fitted(fm))
```

giving:

```
        time values outlier   fitted
1 2010-01-20     11      no 11.64579
2 2010-02-20     12      no 11.49318
3 2010-03-20     11      no 11.35534
4 2010-04-20     12      no 11.20273
5 2010-05-20     10      no 11.05504
6 2010-06-20     20     yes       NA
7 2010-07-20     11      no 10.75474
8 2010-02-20     12      no 11.49318
```

**Note:** The input used, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- 
"time        values    outlier  
20/01/2010   11         no          
20/02/2010   12         no
20/03/2010   11         no
20/04/2010   12         no
20/05/2010   10         no
20/06/2010   20         yes
20/07/2010   11         no
20/02/2010   12         no"

df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
df$time <- as.Date(df$time, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks, does this works if i also have values which are NA?

Comment: It performs the regression on the non-NA values which presumably is what is wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Please check out the following code

```
# Create example data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(time = as.Date(1:100), value = runif(100), outlier = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE))

# Fit model for non-outliers
fit <- lm(value ~ time, df[df$outlier == 0, ] )

# Estimate fitted values for those that are not-outliers
df$regression_points <- ifelse(df$outlier, NA, fitted(fit, df))

#     time     value    outlier regression_points
# 1 1970-01-02 0.2655087       1                NA
# 2 1970-01-03 0.3721239       0         0.5866995
# 3 1970-01-04 0.5728534       0         0.5834598
```

Comment: It works on your example but on mine, I received this error: incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Just tried my code with the data from the other answer and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
fit <- lm(values ~ time, subset=outlier=="no", data=df)
df$regression_points <- NA
df$regression_points[df$outlier=="no"] <- fitted(fit)
```